# How can I extract keys and values from a nested object of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is a question in my last interview and I'm trying to resolve that: in this case, I want to catch values in the nested object and log them into the console.

```
const obj1 = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: {
    foo1: 2,
    bar1: {
      foo2: {
        foo3: 3,
        bar2: 4
      },
      bar3: 5
    }
  }
};

// output: [1,2,3,4,5] //
```

actually, I mean in a professional way. not with this way:

```
[obj1.foo, obj1.bar.foo1, obj1.bar.bar1.foo2.foo3, obj1.bar.bar1.foo2.bar2, obj1.bar.bar1.bar3]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Lots of ways it can be done. Simplest will be manually like this: `[obj1.foo, obj1.bar.foo1, obj1.bar.bar1.foo2.foo3, obj1.bar.bar1.foo2.bar2, obj1.bar.bar1.bar3];`. Do you want to update your question to be more specific?

Comment: thanks. actually, I meant in a professional way. not with this way that you said. but it was fine too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const obj1 = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: {
    foo1: 2,
    bar1: {
      foo2: {
        foo3: 3,
        bar2: 4
      },
      bar3: 5
    }
  }
};

const getValues = (data, values= []) => {
  if(typeof data !== 'object'){
    return [...values, data]
  }
  return Object.values(data).flatMap(v => getValues(v, values))
}

console.log(getValues(obj1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get specific property like this:

```
> function nestedObject (nested) {
>     for (const key in nested) {
>       if (typeof nested[key] === 'object') {
>         for (const nesty in nested[key]) {
>            console.log(nested[key][nesty]);
>         }
>       } else {
>         console.log(nested[key]);
>       }
>     }   }
>      nestedObject(obj1);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: your answer doesn't work